# Улечься «на кровать» или «на кровати»?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

В Интернете, вроде, встречаются обе формы (В.п. и Пр.п.). Улёгся «на ковёр»/«на ковре», «на кровать»/«на кровати», «на матрас»/«на матрасе». Есть ли одна правильная форма, а если нет, то в чём разница?

Comment: «на кровать» is [Illative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illative_case), «на кровати» is [Locative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case) (Russian language has neither, by the way). Both forms can be considered correct, and their meaning is subtly nuanced.

Comment: @Alexander Russian does have rudimentary Locative case also labeled 2nd Prepositional, it's recognized by linguists.... кстати, почему на английском? ))))

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка Да как-то уже привык, что даже на russian.stackexchange основной язык - английский.

Comment: @Alexander, если бы вы написали свой коммент на русском, я бы с вами с удовольствием подискутировал, а так... какие-то непонятные иллятивные-локативные падежы. 11 лет изучал - никогда не слышал. Вопрос-то, кстати, на русском.

Comment: Да, конечно. В русском языке известны 6 основных падежей, а также некоторое количество [Дополнительных падежей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8). В данном случае «на кровать» относится к [Иллатив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2), а «на кровати» - к [Местному падежу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6). Обе формы корректны.

Comment: Спасибо @Alexander. Кстати, прошу прощения за неуместную критику. Не знал, что существует ещё и rus.stackexchange.com, где русский является рабочим языком. Честно говоря хотелось бы, чтоб этот вопрос мигрировали туда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То же ***усесться***

На мой взгляд разница такова, что с В.п. слово в целом синонимично слову ***сесть*** с примесью определённого оттенка.

С П.п. оно (в моём понимании) означает "*лечь так, чтобы было комфортно*", в этом значении его синонимом является слово ***умоститься***.
Иногда его значение совпадает со словом ***разлечься*** или универсальным ***развалиться***, то есть "*лечь, заняв неприлично много места*", в коннотации которого также присутствует оттенок комфорта, потому что комфортное лежание/сидение предполагают остутствие какого бы то ни было пространственного стеснения.

Кроме этого я бы добавил, что в В.п. акцентируется место/предмет, на который ложатся, потому что сам образ действия довольно тривиален, а в П.п. наоборот - способ размещения.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое дополнение. Как *способ размещения* вариант **на кровати** может иметь ещё один аспект употребления (кроме того, *каким образом возлежать*): кровать может акцентироваться как *альтернативное место* (**на чём = где**) по отношению к другому (напр. дивану); в этом случае не важен вариант глагола со значением "ложиться":

> На ночь он отдал в распоряжение гостя *диван в гостиной*, а сам улёгся **на кровати** в спальне.